# Material UI TreeView unexpectedly toggles node when context menu item is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, treeview

I extended [material ui tree view demo](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tree-view/#rich-object) by adding a context menu for each node, using the following .tsx code ([sandbox demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tree-view-with-context-menu-9h5llg?file=/demo.tsx)).

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Typography, Menu, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";
import TreeView from "@mui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";

interface RenderTree {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  children?: readonly RenderTree[];
}

const data: RenderTree = {
  id: "root",
  name: "Parent",
  children: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Child - 1"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      name: "Child - 3",
      children: [
        {
          id: "4",
          name: "Child - 4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const NodeWithContextMenu = (props) => {
  const [contextMenu, setContextMenu] = React.useState<{
    mouseX: number;
    mouseY: number;
  } | null>(null);

  const handleContextMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setContextMenu(
      contextMenu === null
        ? {
            mouseX: event.clientX + 2,
            mouseY: event.clientY - 6
          }
        : // repeated contextmenu when it is already open closes it with Chrome 84 on Ubuntu
          // Other native context menus might behave different.
          // With this behavior we prevent contextmenu from the backdrop to re-locale existing context menus.
          null
    );
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setContextMenu(null);
  };

  return (
    <div onContextMenu={handleContextMenu} style={{ cursor: "context-menu" }}>
      <Typography>{props.label}</Typography>
      <Menu
        open={contextMenu !== null}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorReference="anchorPosition"
        anchorPosition={
          contextMenu !== null
            ? { top: contextMenu.mouseY, left: contextMenu.mouseX }
            : undefined
        }
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Copy</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Print</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Highlight</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Email</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function RichObjectTreeView() {
  const renderTree = (nodes: RenderTree) => (
    <TreeItem
      key={nodes.id}
      nodeId={nodes.id}
      label={<NodeWithContextMenu label={nodes.name} />}
    >
      {Array.isArray(nodes.children)
        ? nodes.children.map((node) => renderTree(node))
        : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );

  return (
    <TreeView
      aria-label="rich object"
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpanded={["root"]}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      sx={{ height: 110, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: "auto" }}
    >
      {renderTree(data)}
    </TreeView>
  );
}
```

On selecting a right-click context menu item the underlying tree node is toggled (expanded or contracted).  This happens when either clicking on the context menu item or anywhere else to close the context menu.

[image: demo gif]

Expected behavior: The use of the context menu should **not** toggle the underlying node.

Here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dzks85?file=/demo.tsx) for the basic mui.com demo and my [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tree-view-with-context-menu-9h5llg?file=/demo.tsx) above.

Comment: @AllanBowe please do not edit code from off-site locations into posts here, unless they are your own posts. You might be violating copyrights unknowingly. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304331/325771 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348698/5211833 for reference.

Comment: Hi @Adriaan - thanks for your concern and moderation efforts.  I'm working with Sabir on this and we would like a proper solution to support our open source product (https://server.sasjs.io)

Comment: `event.stopPropagation` at the start of `handleClose` function can possibly solve the problem.

Comment: Here's the [solution](https://github.com/sasjs/server/pull/313) to my problem in case someone else needs a reference

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem when trying to expand only by clicking on icon and prevent the click on label to expand.

Here is a workaround.

You need to import the TreeViewContext

Prevent the label click from being processed by the wrapped TreeItem.

Use the normal click handling code omitting the toggle expansion logic.

thus in your case you need to customize the contextMenu event handler...

```
function ExpandIconOnlyTreeItem(props:TreeItemProps){
  const {label,...other} = props;
  const context = useContext(TreeViewContext.default) as any;

  const focused = context.isFocused ? context.isFocused(props.nodeId) : false;
  const labelClicked = useCallback(
    (event:any) => {
      if (!focused) {
        context.focus(props.nodeId);
      }
  
      const multiple = context.multiSelect && (event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey);
  
      
  
      if (!context.selectionDisabled) {
        if (multiple) {
          if (event.shiftKey) {
            context.selectRange(event, { end: props.nodeId });
          } else {
            context.selectNode(event, props.nodeId, true);
          }
        } else {
          context.selectNode(event, props.nodeId);
        }
      }
      event.stopPropagation()
      if (props.onClick) {
        props.onClick(event);
      }
    }
  ,[]);
  
  return <TreeItem {...other} label={<span onClick={labelClicked}>{label}</span>}/>
}
```